# UPGRADE FAILED: YAML parse error on app/templates/configmap.i18n.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I just created a new Helm chart but when I run

```
helm upgrade -i
```

I get following error:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: YAML parse error on app/templates/configmap.i18n.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 19: could not find expected ':'
```

This is my configmap.i18n.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "app.name" . }}-i18n-configuration
  labels:
    {{- include "app.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
data:
  {{- range $lang, $messages := .Values.application.i18n }}
  {{ $lang }}: |
    {{ $messages }}
  {{- end }}
```

and i18n is given in value.yaml as following:

```
  i18n:
    en: |
      site.name="T"
      site.name.Server="Tether"
      site.name.Test="Test"
    fa: |
      site.name="ت"
      site.name.Server="تتر"
      site.name.Test="تست"
```

If the value file is as following, everythin works fine.

```
  i18n:
    en: |
      site.name="T"
    fa: |
      site.name="ت"
```

I want to create messages.properties files through helm configmap. if I enter only one message, evrything works fine but if I add more message, I get error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching, I found out what to do. I changed my configmap.yaml as following:

```
{{- with .Values.application.i18n }}
  {{- toYaml . | nindent 4 }}
{{- end }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The multi-line strings in the values are throwing off the indentation.  Try running `helm template --debug` with the values you show; I expect you will see something like

```yaml
data:
  en: |
    site.name="T"
site.name.Server="Tether"
site.name.Test="Test"
```

where the lines after the first aren't indented at all.

The line ending in `|` in both the Helm values YAML file and the output template introduces a YAML *block scalar*.  The following lines are considered a single string, *with all leading whitespace stripped*.  When you write it out, you need to re-insert the leading whitespace.  The `indent` template function will insert blank spaces at the front of each line in a multi-line string, but you need to make sure that line is not itself indented lest you get double indentation.

```yaml
data:
  {{- range $lang, $messages := .Values.application.i18n }}
  {{ $lang }}: |
{{ $messages | indent 4}}
  {{- end }}
```

In the `metadata:` block you have a similar invocation using `nindent`.  This uses the template whitespace-chomping indicator `{{-` to remove all whitespace before this, including leading whitespace at the start of the line and preceding newlines; and then `nindent` begins the resulting string with a newline.  This would let you apparently-correctly indent the line in the template, though the actual whitespace will be lost.

```yaml
  {{ $lang }}: |
    {{- $messages | nindent 4}}
{{/*- ^             ^      */}}
```